# Autofill python template using a Dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, templates

I want to autofill a template using a dictionary in python.

Here is a MWE

```
temp = """
{name}
"""
mydict = {"name":"pythonic"}
print(temp.format(**mydict))
```

However, my real template has curly brackets inside it. Here is an example that does not work but reflects my actual problem

```
temp = """
{
{name}
}
"""
mydict = {"name":"pythonic"}
print(temp.format(**mydict))
```

The error I get is expected... the solution is not known to me however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(temp.format(**mydict))
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

I would like the output to be

```
{
pythonic
}
```

I guess one solution would be to add "{" and "}" as keys in my dictionary and paste them in as well, but, that seems silly. Particularly since my actual template has curly brackets a few more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double curly braces to escape them:

```py
temp = """
{{
{name}
}}
"""
mydict = {"name":"pythonic"}
print(temp.format(**mydict))
```

This will provide the output you want. You can find this in [the documentation about formatting strings...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)